# Setting text after a bind - radtextbox

Tags: asp.net, telerik

When I insert a new record in a grid:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtRedemptionBeforeMessage" Text='<%#Bind("RedemptionBeforeMessage") %>' runat="server" />
```

I want to be able to:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridEditFormItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
        {
            if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.IsItemInserted)
            {
                //fill in defaults for messages which are required
                RadTextBox radTextBox = (RadTextBox)item.FindControl("txtRedemptionBeforeMessage");

                radTextBox.Text = "default redemption before message";
```

**This works when there is no Text**='<%#Bind("RedemptionBeforeMessage") %>

**Problem:**  how to I get a default message to work - I suspect I need to look at an event after the bind.

The Bind is in there because the same form code is used to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered your question in this thread - [Setting text after a bind - radtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190582/setting-text-after-a-bind-radtextbox)

Comment: Thanks Dick - I put the code below as well that I used to get it working.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dave, see paragraph #3 [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grderrormessages.html) - should get you up and going.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to get it working:

```
public void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName)
        {
            //fill in defaults for messages which are required
            e.Canceled = true;
            ListDictionary newValues = new ListDictionary();
            newValues.Add("name", "default name message");
            newValues.Add("blahblahbindablename", "default blah blah message");
            //Insert the item and rebind
            e.Item.OwnerTableView.InsertItem(newValues);
        }
    }
```